# Dbcontext creating columns that I never made

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a view, which previously got an ID, which is working fine(checked in debugger, ID is correct), to invoke a method:

```
   public ActionResult DetaljiNarudzbe(int id)
        {
            DetaljiNarudzbeViewModel model = new DetaljiNarudzbeViewModel();
            model.Narudzba = ctx.Naruzbee.Where(x => x.Id == id).First();
            model.StatusNarudzbe = ctx.StatusiNarudzbi.Where(x => x.Id == model.Narudzba.StatusNarudzbeId).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Primaoc = ctx.Primaoci.Where(x => x.Id == model.Narudzba.PrimaocId).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Adresa = ctx.Adrese.Where(x => x.Id == model.Narudzba.AdresaId).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Grad = ctx.Gradovi.Where(x => x.Id == model.Adresa.GradId).FirstOrDefault();
            model.StavkeNarudzbe = ctx.StavkeNarudzbi.Where(x => x.Narudzbe_Id == id).ToList();
            model.Klijent = ctx.Klijenti.Where(x => x.Id == model.Narudzba.KlijentId).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Korisnik = ctx.Korisnici.Where(x => x.Id == model.Klijent.KorisnikId).FirstOrDefault();
            return View("DetaljiNarudzbe", model);
        }
```

However, it keeps crashing at this part

```
 model.StavkeNarudzbe = ctx.StavkeNarudzbi.Where(x => x.Narudzbe_Id == id).ToList();
```

It throws an exception, because for some reason, I think the context created another column called Narudzbe_Id1, which can't be null.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozEI8.jpg - Image of the given exception

Further proof that it's an issue with dbcontext:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtotk.jpg

The extra column doesn't appear in the database on the SQL server's side, where I'm getting the data from.

If it helps, I'm posting the other relevant classes below:

```
   public class StavkaNarudzbe : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public int Tezina { get; set; }
        public double Cijena { get; set; }
        public int Narudzbe_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Narudzbe Narudzbe { get; set; }
    }

public class MojKontekst : DbContext
    {
        public MojKontekst() : base("DostavaConnString")
        {

        }
       public DbSet<Adresa> Adrese { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Grad> Gradovi { get; set; }
       public DbSet<DetaljiVozila> DetaljiVozilaa { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Klijent> Klijenti { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Korisnik> Korisnici { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Kurir> Kuriri { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Kvar> Kvarovi { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Obavijest> Obavijesti { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Narudzbe> Naruzbee { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Posiljka> Posiljke { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Prelazi> Prelazii { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Primaoc> Primaoci { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Skladiste> Skladista { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StatusNarudzbe> StatusiNarudzbi { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StavkaNarudzbe> StavkeNarudzbi { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vozilo> Vozila { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VrstaVozila> VrsteVozila { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)    
        {   
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
        }

  public class DetaljiNarudzbeViewModel
    {
        public Klijent Klijent;
        public Korisnik Korisnik;
        public Narudzbe Narudzba;
        public List<StavkaNarudzbe> StavkeNarudzbe;
        public StatusNarudzbe StatusNarudzbe;
        public Primaoc Primaoc;
        public Adresa Adresa;
        public Grad Grad;
    }

  public class Narudzbe : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string SifraNarudzbe { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatumNarudzbe { get; set; }
        public bool Osigurano { get; set; }
        public bool BrzaDostava { get; set; }
        public int BrojPaketa { get; set; }
        public int KlijentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Klijent Klijent { get; set; }
        public int AdresaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Adresa Adresa { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PosiljkaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Posiljka Posiljka { get; set; }
        public int StatusNarudzbeId { get; set; }
        public virtual StatusNarudzbe StatusNarudzbe{ get; set; }
        public int PrimaocId { get; set; }
        public virtual Primaoc Primaoc { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> VrijemeIsporuke { get; set; }
        public int CijenaNarudzbe { get; set; }
    }
```

Exception Text: Invalid column name Narudzbe_Id1

Comment: What happens when you remove all lines but the problematic one and the creation of the model?

Comment: If you remove public int Narudzbe_Id { get; set; }
and instead use:
model.StavkeNarudzbe = ctx.StavkeNarudzbi.Where(x => x.Narudzbe.Id == id).ToList();
do you get same error?

Comment: Well, for some reason, removing the _ in NarudzbeID in both the model class and the database and then rebuilding the solution seems to have done the trick.

Now column in the StavkaNarudzbe table in both the database and class is NarudzbaID and it's not creating an extra one anymore

Comment: Please post the exception text instead of an image. Also, can you please post the code for `Narudzbe` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Entity Framework trying to follow it's standard naming conventions for relationship columns.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164(v=vs.113).aspx for more information this.

As you are using non-standard names for your foreign key columns (i.e. Narudzbe_Id should be NarudzbeId) you'll need to let EF know how to link up your models. Either rename the properties of your classes to follow this naming convention, or use Data Annotations to explicitly tell EF about your relationships.

For example, try adding a ForeignKey attribute (found in the `System.Componentmodel.Dataannotations.Schema` namespace) like so:

```
 public class StavkaNarudzbe : IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string Naziv { get; set; }
        public int Tezina { get; set; }
        public double Cijena { get; set; }
        public int Narudzbe_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Narudzbe_Id")]
        public virtual Narudzbe Narudzbe { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I did rename the column and rebuild the solution and it worked fine, thanks.